# The separate shortcut doesn't work

Tags: shortcut

I tried to change the separate shortcut to another button in preferences, But it still didn't work, I can use the scale and move shortcut and other shortcuts, I tried reinstalling blender deleting the left over files too, The blender version that I am using is 2.83.2

This problem didn't happen before it used to work fine
here is a screenshot of the separate keymap
http://prntscr.com/tidli7
I tried download a previous version of blender 2.82a
but the problem still stands.

Comment: Hi. Please add details/screenshots of what steps you did to change the shortcut and what the result is when you try and use the shortcut. You can use the [edit] link below your question to add more details. Thanks.

Comment: I am dumb, I had to change to edit mode first to separate sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

I had to be in edit mode in order for the separate shortcut to work.